# How to represent all possible object paths in a tuple types

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Given an object `type SomeRecord = {a: {a1: 'a1', a2: 'a2'}, b: {b1: 'b1'}}`, I want a type `Path<T extends Record<string, any>>` that represents all possible record paths as tuples:

```js
// Path<SomeRecord> will be a union of:
['a']
['a', 'a1']
['a', 'a2']
['b']
['b', 'b1']
// And nothing else
```

I read a [ton of suggestions](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12290) where the path is a parameter of a function. That doesn't work for me because I only need the tuples.

Comment: The duplicated answer has a `Paths` that works this way, although it's not supported.  Your case would work like... (next comment)

Comment: like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwM4B4ASAaKAVAfFAXhyggA9gIEATJKAJwgEMrEAbEKRhEAbQF0oAfgCwAKCgSoACikALAFxRMUAHRrgi7AEpC+AG5wAllR1kK1WjLUq6iwwgBmEOlABKOgvqMmhbqIoQIPWcxSX8oQOC6AG4xUEgoAAUGPUIoHkjnLAAGLABGLAAmLABmLAAWLABWLAA2LAB2LAAOLABOfNyoPILu4u6y7srumu767qbu1u6OqEKu62z+PjjwaETGYFlUbCwAERJyShoIgFcAWwAjZzS87PwiHj2BM2PaDKDnAUEIz5dNQ7mE5wS4AKwgAGNgEJQpIAN7pADSUHsUAA1hAQHAHDg+ABaQSKHiIgQAH2kGy2O2JfCwySCTz4+FeFhRjhuiRh4jCkk5LJO-F8mX+sEQqERdPwAT+sIkOgAvjwMVicdgVtyJES+LFRPFoABlODnCCuSFwOhUNJwxiKa15RQAckYeQdWEYhUd7od8qwl1tl3tUAdAe98tWCQAsiBKds0jHUIbjaaIeaqLhokA).

Comment: @jcalz ahh, that's too bad. As my question is way more concise : ) Thanx for the answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before we start, not that generating a union of all possible paths might be expensive. in terms of compilation time. Also the solution below uses recursive conditional types, which have their own perf issues and their use is not encouraged.

The most elegant solution is to use the new TS feature in 4.0 (unreleased yet) that allows spreading of tuples in other tuples, as described [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/39094). With this and with a recursive conditional type we can create a all the possible tuple paths:

```
type SomeRecord = { a: { a1: 'a1', a2: 'a2' }, b: { b1: 'b1', b2: { b21: string, b22: string, } } }


type Paths<T, K extends keyof T = keyof T> = K extends K ? [K, ...{
    0: []
    1: [] | Paths<T[K]>    
}[T[K] extends string | number | boolean ? 0: 1]] : never;

type x = Paths<SomeRecord>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=4.0.0-beta#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgJQgYzgJwCZQLxQDeUAhgFxGkCMFA5CVbQDSkBMdJrtUAviwEYVi-GlFojmUfu0rTRAZ2CYAlgDsA5gNYzFKjSx69eAWABQZs6EhQACiWAALeQB4AKiwDSUCAA9gEVWx5KABrCBA4ADMoV3xQ8KiYgD44r19-QOCvAH4oAG0PFgA6EsIzKAqoAAYKPIBdcsrReqgAH1t7JzcCupTKsx481x7vPwCgqF01dTaoVQBXBH4ITFn+ODgAGwgSVShcmqgqOrqoClUIADcVgG4LUytoHzi7Rxd4JFQMHBSAel+KnkAEQkIGndrA0EsEFUMGzSFA6GcOEQoH8FH5NGIqBo2HgzHo6HSDHAwk44lE1h4+FYynYtHaMHlIA)

The way it works, is we take each key in `T`, and use a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) to take each key `K` and create a tuple, where `K` is the first item, followed by a spread of:

- either the empty tuple (`[]`) if `T[K]` has no other keys we are interested in (ie is a primitive) o
- or a tuple made from `[]` (in order to allow just `[K]`) in union with the paths of the type of `T[K]`.

Unormalized the result would be something like `['a', ...([] | ['a1'] | ['a2'])] | ['b', ...([] | ['b1'] | ['b2', ...([] | ['b21'] | ['b22'] ])]`. Fortunately the compiler will normalize that monstrosity to `["a"] | ["a", "a1"] | ["a", "a2"] | ["b"] | ["b", "b1"] | ["b", "b2"] | ["b", "b2", "b21"] | ["b", "b2", "b22"]`

Comment: Badass. 4.0 seem just out the door, but, are you able to come up with something for the current TS?

Comment: Also, looking at `K extends K`, how is it possible for `K` to not extend `K`?

Comment: @DanielBirowskyPopeski I'm working on it, but I get `Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.`  errors and i'm trying to work around those. If I come up with something I'll post ..

Comment: @DanielBirowskyPopeski `K extends K` will always be true, it's there to trigger distribution over `K` see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types

Comment: I don't mind if you come up with a solution with union of hardcoded arities : )

Comment: I closed this q as a duplicate of another... do you want to put your answer there?

Comment: Here's a continuation of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63022359/592641